# Display Google Map API route on map

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am new to google Map Api V3, and i am planning to find the best route among some waypoint.

I found that the direction API could solve my problem (http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?...)

I got the Json output, but is there any way to display the route on Google map directly?

Or i should parse the Json, get the legs information, and plot it again??

Thanks a lot

Comment: i think there is no other way to do this because if you depend on any other service like location manager, then it cause problem.If location is not update frequently then on the map straight line is draw.So better way is that you have to called Api

Comment: so u mean i have to call the direction API, parse the json, then draw the points out?

Comment: yes i think so, but if other not give any solution